# How to include .dll file in CAPL?

Tags: c, capl

I tried to use the bellow command to include the .dll file in my CAPL code but I got the following warning:

> Warning     2102 at (6,20): Could not open
>   C:\Users\Desktop\OpenSSL_MacGen\OpenSSL_MacGen\Debug\OpenSSL_MacGen.dll,
>   The specified module could not be found.

```
#pragma library ("OpenSSL_MacGen\OpenSSL_MacGen\Debug\OpenSSL_MacGen.dll")
```

Comment: Is that where the file is? Generally in C or C++ code the proper directive is `#pragma comment(lib, "library name")`

Comment: yes it the right bath. I am using CAPL code and vector people directed to use #pragma library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341136/how-to-include-a-h-or-dll-file-in-canoe-capl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197975/how-to-access-dll-file-via-capl

Answer (score 1):

excerpt from CANoe help:

> In CAPL programs you can call functions which you have implemented in your own Windows DLL. In doing so, the function from the DLL are exported through a function table.
>
> The CAPL DLL interface supports callback functions starting with CANoe version 5.0.
>
> Whenever functions of a DLL are called in the real-time area (i.e. in Simulation Setup of CANoe), they run in a high-priority thread. This can affect measurement.
>
> In order for the CAPL compiler and CAPL browser to recognize the DLL, you must link it to the CAPL program.
>   To do this, proceed as follows:
>
> Enter the DLL in the Options dialog in CANoe. 
>   In this case, the DLL will be available to all CAPL programs. 
>   You can enter the DLL in the includes section of a CAPL program using the #pragma library command.
>   In this case, it will only be available to this program.

Easiest way is to use templates available on PC with CANoe installed. 
Have a look into: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Vector\CANoe\9.0 (x64)\CANoe Sample Configurations\Programming\CAPLdll (or similar depending on your version of CANoe)